# Temperature conversion program for college

Tags: java, function, compilation

```
//Name: Eric Stum
//Date: 2/20/2019
//desciption: Homework 4

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class TemperatureConverter{

  public static void convertTemp(String tempScale, String Answer, double temp, double result){

if(tempScale.equals("f") && Answer.equals("yes")) 
{ 
double scale1 = (0.5555555555555556);//had troubles with the faction for some reason :/
result = scale1 * (temp - 32); 
System.out.println(temp + " is equal to " + result + " degrees celsius. "); 
}    
else if(tempScale.equals("c") && Answer.equals("yes")){
result = (temp * 1.8) + 32.0;
System.out.println(temp + " is equal to " + result + " degrees farenheight. ");
}
else{
System.out.println("invalid entry");
    }

   }

   //main method
   public static void main(String args[]){
         double result;
         double temp;
   String tempScale;

   System.out.println("Hello. This Program will convert Farenheight to Celcius or vise-versa.");


   Scanner keyboard1 = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);


   System.out.println("To get started please enter a temperature");
   temp = keyboard2.nextDouble();
   System.out.println("Did you submit Farenheight or Celsius?");
     System.out.println("Type f for farenheight or c for celsius: ");
    tempScale = keyboard1.nextLine();

     if (tempScale.equals("f") || tempScale.equals("F")){
     System.out.println("you entered in " + temp + " degrees farenheight.");
      }
      else if (tempScale.equals("c") || tempScale.equals("C")){
      System.out.println("you entered in " + temp + " degrees celsius.");
      }
      else{
      System.out.println("invalid entry");
      }   

     System.out.println("would you like to convert it?");
     Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
     String Answer = keyboard3.nextLine();

     convertTemp();

     }
   }
```

So I am a student at a university, and i am trying to figure out this homework assignment and have yet to find an answer. I keep getting errors about the method invoking, no matter what i try, can anybody help me figure how to successfully invoke the method into the main method. Really need help with this?

But I keep getting this error:

> TemperatureConverter.java:62: error: method convertTemp in class 
>   TemperatureConverter cannot be applied to given types;

```
 convertTemp();
 ^
```

> required: String,String,double,double
>   found: no arguments
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>   1 error
>
> ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
>   ----jGRASP: operation complete.

Answer (score 2):

Your function definition says it expects 4 parameters:

```
public static void convertTemp(
      String tempScale, 
      String Answer, 
      double temp,  
      double result)
```

but when you call it, you pass 0 parameters:

```
convertTemp();
```

Comment: thank you, that helped a lot, fixed it and now it runs smoothly.

Comment: Glad to help.  Feel free to mark my answer as correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the parameters for your `convertTemp()` method inside your `main`. :)